# Cannot upload big file to sharepoint

Tags: java, file, sharepoint, file-upload, microsoft-graph-api

```
    String tenantId = "072aa4c6-xxx";
    String clientId = "f0e1e49c-xxx";
    String clientSecret = "QrJ8Q-xxx";

    // Set the authority URL for your tenant
    String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId;

    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            }
    };

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .sslSocketFactory(createInsecureSslSocketFactory(), new TrustAllCerts())
            .hostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true)
            .build();


    // Create a ConfidentialClientApplication instance
    ConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(
                    clientId, ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(clientSecret))
            .authority(authority)
            .build();




    // Set the scopes for the access token
    Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<>();
    scopes.add("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");


    // Create a ClientCredentialParameters instance
    ClientCredentialParameters parameters = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(
                    Collections.singleton("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default")).scopes(scopes)
            .build();


    // Acquire an access token
    CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireToken(parameters);
    CompletableFuture<String> accessTokenFuture = future.thenApply(result -> result.accessToken());
    String accessToken = accessTokenFuture.get();
    String[] parts = accessToken.split("\\.");
    String decoded = new String(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(parts[1]));

    System.out.println("decoded " + decoded);


    String spoFolder = siteBaseFolder + spoPath;
    String url = "/sites/"+siteId+"/Drives/"+driveId+"/root:/"+ spoFolder +"/" +inputFile.getName();
    System.out.println(url);

    //String accessToken = this.oauthService.getAccessToken().getAccessToken();
    System.out.println("access token : " + accessToken);
    IAuthenticationProvider authProvider = url1 -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture("Bearer " + accessToken);

    GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient();
    System.out.println("graph client: " + graphClient);

    // Get an input stream for the file
    File file = new File(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println(file);
    InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    long streamSize = file.length();
    System.out.println(streamSize);

    final DriveItemCreateUploadSessionParameterSet uploadParams = DriveItemCreateUploadSessionParameterSet
            .newBuilder().withItem(new DriveItemUploadableProperties()).build();

    final UploadSession uploadSession = graphClient.sites(siteId).drives(driveId).root()
            .itemWithPath(url).createUploadSession(uploadParams).buildRequest()
            .post();

    if (null == uploadSession) {
        fileStream.close();
        throw new Exception("Could not create upload session");
    }

    // Create a callback used by the upload provider
    final IProgressCallback callback = new IProgressCallback() {
        @Override
        // Called after each slice of the file is uploaded
        public void progress(final long current, final long max) {
            System.out.println(
                    String.format("Uploaded %d bytes of %d total bytes", current, max));
        }
    };

    LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem> largeFileUploadTask = new LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem>(
            uploadSession, graphClient, fileStream, streamSize, DriveItem.class);

    // Do the upload
    largeFileUploadTask.upload(0, null, callback);

}
```

I have the above piece of code , but i keep getting invalid access token error, I have configured a azure app for this and assigned sites selected permissions to it, what am I doing wrong here.

```
{
    "aio": "**********",
    "app_displayname": "ACE File Uploader",
    "appid": "f0e1e49c-4782-4faa-bd5a-23981390c977",
    "appidacr": "1",
    "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
    "exp": 1706061750,
    "iat": 1706057850,
    "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/**********/",
    "idtyp": "app",
    "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/**********/",
    "nbf": 1706057850,
    "oid": "ca6a9893-cc50-4299-af58-7532f0e56603",
    "rh": "0.AVQAxqQqB5qhRECzWpARKZMr3AMAAAAAAAAAwAAAAAAAAACiAAA.",
    "roles": [
        "Sites.Selected"
    ],
    "sub": "ca6a9893-cc50-4299-af58-7532f0e56603",
    "tenant_region_scope": "AS",
    "tid": "**********",
    "uti": "zFlliaE0EEqi78IvKO6HAA",
    "ver": "1.0",
    "wids": [
        "0997a1d0-0d1d-4acb-b408-d5ca73121e90"
    ],
    "xms_tcdt": 1398146826
}
```

The token i get looks like above
am i doing something wrong here ?

for azure app api permissions under configured permissions i have microsoft graph 4 permissions

```
Files.readwrite.ALL
Sites.ReadWrtie.All
sites.selected
user.selected
```

Whats missing here , why do i get an invalid access token when im trying to post the request to upload the big file ?